# How to find/kill zombie task in taskscheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have a task that runs an exe every minute.

I noticed odd behaviour, and see that the exe is being run twice every minute.

I have "ended" and disabled the task in the taskscheduler. And now I see that this other "zombie" task continues to run every minute.

How can I find and kill it?

Comment: No that would clear it. But I would like to be able to kill such task WITHOUT a restart

Answer (score 1):

Using `taskkill` will help you with your issue.

The general syntax of the command looks like this:

```
taskkill [OPTIONS] [PID]
```

As you might expect, there are plenty of options available for this command. Some of the more helpful options are:

```
/s COMPUTER -- (Where COMPUTER is the IP or address of a remote computer). The default is the local computer, so if you're working with a command on the local machine, you do not have to use this option.
/u DOMAIN\USER -- (Where DOMAIN is the domain and USER is the username you authenticate to). This option allows you run taskkill with the account permissions of the specified USERNAME or DOMAIN\USERNAME.
/p -- If you use the /u option, you will also need to include the /p option, which allows you to specify the user password.
/fi -- Allows you to run the taskkill command with filters.
/f -- Forces the command to be terminated.
/IM -- Allows you to use an application name instead of the PID (Process ID number) of the application.
```

This can be seen on CMD by typing  `taskkill /?`

Use the help switch for the taskkill command.

Killing with application name
The simplest way to kill a rogue application with `taskkill` is using the `/IM` option. This is done like so:

```
taskkill /IM APPLICATION_NAME
```

Where `APPLICATION_NAME` is the name of the application you want to kill. Say, for example, Outlook is refusing to close. To close this with taskkill, you would execute the command:

```
taskkill /IM outlook.exe
```

Hope this helps - good luck!

Comment: Hi, yes I am familiar wiht TASKKILL and TASKLIST - the problem is one of IDENTIFYING the process that is the still running task...

Comment: Ahhhh I see - try this [link](http://www.antionline.com/showthread.php?252029-Identify-rogue-processes-using-netstat-and-the-windows-taskmanager) Let me know if this helps, if not I shall do some more digging. . .